# Get the most frequent string in each row in a single column in R or Python or excel

Tags: python, r, excel

I have a dataframe like image1. I want to convert it to image2.
I have tried r, python, and excel but failed. Excel formula: =INDEX(AV2:AW2,MODE(MATCH(AV2:AW2,AV2:AW2,0))) give me N/A output.
the "k2" column would be the most common element from "knumbers" column. Any Help. Best, Zillur
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you can split the strings on comma, count the frequency using `table` and get the most frequently occurring string.

```
df$k2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$knumbers, ','), function(x) 
                 names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution:

```
# Initialise pandas, and mode in session: 
import pandas as pd
from statistics import mode

# Scalar denoting the full path to file (including file name): filepath => string scalar
filepath = ''

# Read in the Excel sheet: df => Data Frame 
df = pd.read_excel(filepath)

# Find modal element per row: k2 => string vector
df['k2'] = [*map(lambda x: mode(str(x).split(',')), df['knumbers'])]
```

Base R Solution:

```
# Define a function to retrieve the modal element in a factor/character vector: mode_stat => function
mode_stat <- function(chr_vec){names(sort(table(as.character(chr_vec)), decreasing = TRUE)[1])}

# Apply the function to a list of split knumber strings: k2 => character vector
df$k2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$knumbers, ","), mode_stat)
```

Data (reconstruct in R):

```
df <- structure(list(Total = c(446, 346, 332, 308), knumbers = c("K10401", 
"K10413,K10413,K10412", "K13844,K13844,K13845", "K19206,K19207,K19207"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In Excel:

```
 (goodluck)
```